# How can I pass a default argument of other type to a parameter?

Tags: c++, casting, initialization, default-arguments

Lets say I have this prog.cc file:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  unsigned int X : 2;
  unsigned int Y : 2;
  unsigned int Spare : 28;
};

void MyFunc (int x, MyStruct myStruct = 0);


int main ()
{
    MyStruct myStr;
    myStr.X = 1;
    myStr.Y = 0;
    MyFunc(6);
}

void MyFunc (int x, MyStruct myStruct)
{
    x += 10;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.4.7, I got this error:

> prog.cc:7: error: default argument for 'MyStruct myStruct' has type 'int'

Now, I understand the error, but still - how can I resolve this?
I know I need somehow to cast from `int` to `MyStruct`, but both

```
MyStruct myStruct = (MyStruct)0
```

and

```
MyStruct myStruct = static_cast<MyStruct>0
```

has failed with:

> prog.cc:7: error: no matching function for call to 'MyStruct::MyStruct(int)'
>
> prog.cc:1: note: candidates are: MyStruct::MyStruct()
>
> prog.cc:1: note:                 MyStruct::MyStruct(const MyStruct&)

How can I simply initialize my user-defined struct, passed as default argument on function parameter?

(Here is the sample code:
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/izWCnBXl9PGnmm0l)

Comment: What exactly do you expect casting from `0` to a `MyStruct` to do? Initialize all the members to `0`? What if the argument was passed in as `5`? From what I gather (including you specifying sizes of members), I think you'd be better off using a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset).

Answer (score 7):

You can default-initialise PODs, so:

```
void MyFunc (int x, MyStruct myStruct = MyStruct());
```

I guess you're trying to use `0` because, as well as being an integer, that's a null pointer constant. But you're not using pointers here. The use of `0` is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a conversion constructor to your `MyStruct`:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  unsigned int X : 2;
  unsigned int Y : 2;
  unsigned int Spare : 28;
  MyStruct(int n) : X(n&3), Y(n&12), Spare(0) {}
};
```

It's implementation depends on your semantics, but you get the technical point. Enclosing your struct in an union could be a good solution too if you want to make it convertible from/to an `int`.